# How do I set color attribute each text line on HTML corresponding to javascript code line on execution?

Tags: javascript

So let's say thay I have an HTML page like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="script.js"/> <!--this calls my script-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li>var a = 1;</li>
                <li>var a = 2;</li>
                <li>var a = 3;</li>
                <li>var a = 4;</li>
                <li>var a = 5;</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" onclick="HighlightCode()" />
    </body>
</html>
```

And my script.js contains:

```
function HighlightCode()
{
    for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        var a = i + 1;
        var ul = document.getElementByTagName("ul");

        //get each <li> and set color attribute to red
        ul.children[i].style.color = "red";

        // reset previous line back to black
        if(i != 0)
            ul.children[i - 1].style.color = "black";

        // some kind of function that delay the loop 1000ms before increasing variable "i" 
        Sleep(1000); 
        //I have no idea what the function name is in Javascript, in C# I often use Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

I would like to highlight each "li" line at each loop execution!

I hope someone could help! Thank you!

Comment: As far as I can tell, you appear to want a function that keeps painting a line in the list red, while keeping others black. If so, then the concept needs work. FIrst of all, there is no `Sleep` function. Search for `setTimeout` and `setInterval` for alternatives. Then, if the rest of the code is working, you should be fine, if not, please, edit the question, with whatever errors you can log.

Comment: Also, please [check this documentation](http://javascript.info/tutorial/traversing-dom) to see if it solves your issue.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using CSS and JavaScript:

CSS:

```
@keyframes test{
    0%{color:black}
    50%{color:red}
    100%{color:black}
}

.blinkyNode{
    animation-name: test;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-timing-function: steps(1,start);
}
```

javascript:

```
HighlightCode = function(){
    var ul = document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];
    for(var i = 0; i < ul.children.length;i++){        
      ul.children[i].className = "";    
      ul.children[i].style.animationDelay = "";
      ul.children[i].offsetWidth = ul.children[i].offsetWidth;
      ul.children[i].style.animationDelay = i+"s";
      ul.children[i].className = "blinkyNode";
    }
}
```

Notes:

- `getElementByTagName` does not exist. it's `getElementsByTagName` and returns an array.
- Submit buttons are for forms only
- the `offsetWidth`  = `offsetWidth` thing is necessary because else the browser doesn't realise the class has been readded.

[test the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lkd0b4m4/2/)